# About findfile function. what is "." and ".." directory?

Tags: c, file

[image: this is my FindFile program]

I have one question.

What are "." and ".." directory?
What are they doing?
Why are they searched?
I don't have . and .. directory in that folder which I wanted to search.
I wonder. tell me please ...
Here, it's the findfile code:

```
GetWindowsDirectory(Path,MAX_PATH);
lstrcat(Path,"\\*.*");
hSrch=FindFirstFile(Path,&wfd);
if (hSrch==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;
while (bResult) {
    if (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
        wsprintf(fname,"[ %s ]",wfd.cFileName);
    } else {
        wsprintf(fname,"%s",wfd.cFileName);
    }
    SendMessage(hList,LB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM)fname);
    bResult=FindNextFile(hSrch,&wfd);
}
FindClose(hSrch);
```

Comment: when you list paths you have current dir (`.`) and parent dir (`..`) unless you're at the root dir. Always filter them out from your directory scan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm practicing this to use it for loading some images and sound. should I do like this? if(fname != TEXT(".")) like that? uh.. to sort out "." and ".."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have `.` and `..` directory in that folder which I wanted to search.

You always have these intrinsic directories at any POSIX compliant file system.

`.` denotes the current working directory.

`..` denotes the parent directory.